# Stripe transfer receipt

Tags: stripe-payments, transfer, receipt

I am developing app where transfer money from platform to connect when completing some task.
And then my app customers can get money in their stripe account.
I think they need to get receipt for getting earning when using my app but I can't see how to send receipts to customer's email for transferring.
I know it can by specifying receipts_email when charing and refund but no such stuff in transfer object.
How can my app send receipt to customer for transferring ?
if it's impossible what is providing instead in stripe?
Really I need to get help.
Thank you.
[image: stripe dashboard email receipts setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email receipt feature is only available for Charges which happen when you charge a Customer's card. This is documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/receipts

Stripe does not send email receipts when you transfer funds to a connected account or when funds are sent to their own bank accounts. This is something that you would need to build on your side instead based on the funds you're sending to them.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Receipts email would be needed for proof of taxes customer's payment or earning. if stripe receipt is not available for transfer my app customize email will be proof for taxes instead?